# how to draw many to many relationship by logical model

Tags: database, entity-relationship

Here is the **background**:

Bottles are acquired from the suppliers by placing orders. Some bottle types may be ordered from more than 
one supplier. Each order involves only a single supplier but may include more than one bottle type. Usually 
orders are filled completely by the suppliers, but occasionally an order must be filled with multiple shipments, 
due to a back-order condition at the supplier. WWWC maintains careful records of what quantities are 
ordered and what quantities are received, as well as when the bottles are ordered and when they are 
received, and the actual price charged for the bottles.

The **conceptual model** of **bottle** is: Bottle{ID, Capacity, Shape, Material, Color, Cost, Quantity}

The  **conceptual model** of **Supplier** is: Supplier{ID, Name, Phone#, Address, Contact_Name}.

Till now, I know that the relationship between Bottles and Suppliers are many-to-many.
Here is the photo of the E-R relationship, just omit attributes(you can get them from the conceptual model above).
[image]

As far as I know, converting from ER relationship to logical diagram under the many-to-many relationship, I need to create another table to represent the relationship.
So I create another table called: Purchase, which contains follow attributes: SID(Supplier ID), BID(Bottle ID), Ordered_Quantity, Received_Quantity, When_Ordered， When_Received.

**My Question is: How to use lines to connect those three tables to establish the relationship?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like in the image below. [Crow's foot notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model) is used here but more notations are possible such as idef1x. Most ER modeling tools support multiple of these notation techniques. This example is made with [Dezign](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/index.html)

[image: example]